# Nebulizer on Yom Kippur

Tags: halacha, fast-days, medicine, yom-kippur, eating

Is someone who suffers from asthma and needs to use a nebulizer to make it easier for them to breath (not pekuach nefesh) allowed to use it on Yom Kippur? (In a way of course that it'll be turned on for example by using a Shabbos Clock.) Is the inhaling of the mist/steam/whatever comes out considered to be like drinking or not?

(This is a theoretical shailo that I'm only looking for sources on or possible re'as to formulate a teshuva to this.)

Comment: Rabbi Rudinsky said that the issur is specifically consumption and he has said that if you can find another way to feel full, for example through acupuncture that would be permitted.

Comment: Acupuncture? Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was asked about IV feeding (rather than eating) and said you violate Yom Kippur by inserting a needle into your arm -- the only question would be if someone already had the IV inserted.

Comment: @Shalom the IV provides nutrients which would qualify as consumption, acupuncture does not provide the nutrients, it simply relieves the feeling of hunger.

Comment: These comments seem to be a little off topic (albeit interesting, but not nege'ah to this shailo...)

Comment: @PM I think he meant because of melacha.

Comment: @DoubleAA you don't need to do the acupuncture on yom kippur, you can do it beforehand

Comment: I am inclined to think that if the nebulizer were a problem, it might be equally forbidden to deliberately stand in an area of natural high humidity - which bearing in mind the recent weather where I live could be a real problem.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, the nebulizer does more than provide humid air (that would be a humidifier).  It provides some sort of medication for breathing ease.  It might be prohibited on the basis of the medicine alone, seperate from the delivery method.  Healthy people certainly don't use a nebulizer.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Assuming of course there is no issue of taking medicine because the person needs this in order to breathe easier

Comment: Note that an asthma sufferer's need for albuterol or the like is often _pikuach nefesh_ despite the specific question here that assumes the case is one that's _not_ of _pikuach nefesh_. In any event, as the question notes, if this question may be applicable to any reader, he should consult his rabbi and doctor before _Yom Kipur_ to determine the correct course of action.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Even if you could be sure that it wasn't pikuach nefesh, difficulty breathing would still likely make the person considered *choleh kol gufo*, in which case medicine is permitted.

Comment: -1. I still don't understand why you would think that it might be forbidden.

Comment: Every so often I see a comment that I wrote long ago and am surprised at how much I still like my comment.  Now, I very much dislike my comment.  How do you ever have a case of using a nebulizer that it isn't pikuach nefesh?  Is it used for anything besides asthma, which very much is pikuach nefesh (even if it is not now acute).

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen, yes, a nebulizer is used for things other than asthma, for medication delivery into the lungs for a variety of conditions, quite commonly for small children's lung infections, and skipping a day for Yom Kippur is not Pikuach Nefesh, TTBOMK. Of course children are different, but adults can get the same prescription in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

I asked this very question (for a family member) to Rabbi Gedalia Anemer, zt'l, regarding Shabboss and all yom tovim (including Yom Kippur).  He said it was not a problem.

Comment: The question specificaly was **not** asking about the melacha aspect, but rather about the drinking aspect (which does not apply to "Shabboss and all yom tovim" .....unless you were told specifically that Yom Kippur is included in this, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I thought there was an exception for people who are ill. If not taking your meds on Yom Kippur will make you seriously sick or cause serious adverse affects, you should just take your meds. Somewhere that's recognized. There are many life-saving exceptions like that all over Judaism.

Comment: The question specifically mentions that this is not a pikuach nefesh situation

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know what that meant until i read your comment. :)

Answer (score -2):

Of course it's fine. Breathing is not drinking. Humid air is no different than regular air. If it was, then you could only breathe air that had 0% humidity, which is obviously ridiculous.

Comment: There could well be a difference between breathing air at its natural humidity and artificially altering it.  I've found it best to not assume that anything is "obvious".  Your response would probably get a better reception if you were to edit it to sound less confrontational ("of coursse", "obviously ridicoulous").  You may well be right that breathing (any) air isn't a problem; can you support that with either sources or an argument?

Comment: Breathing≠Eating, and unless you have a source to contradict the obvious, yhy do I need a source when there likely is none? Just use use logic. Air is "artificially" altered when you use an air conditioner too. That's not what matters, just like drinking water from a natural river or from a cup is equally forbidden.

Comment: 'Of course'? There could be some unknown reason to prohibit this, so making a simple comparison isn't really an answer.